# How to create a vector that for each column in a data frame indicates whether or not it’s a factor

Tags: r, purrr

I am working on Chapter 17 of R for Data Science: Iteration with purrr.

One exercise has this newbie stuck:

How can you create a single vector that for each column in a data frame indicates whether or not it’s a factor?

Here's what I have come up with:

```
library(tidyverse)
map(mtcars, is.factor(.$names(mtcars)))
```

Which obviously doesn't work. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: try `map_lgl(mtcars, is.factor)`

Comment: Or simply `sapply(mtcars, is.factor)`.

Comment: Are you obliged to use `purrr`? If not, `apply(mtcars, 2, is.factor)` does the job.

Comment: Thanks! So for a dataframe each column is the element?

Comment: A dataframe is essentially a `list`, where each list element is one column. `lapply`, `sapply` etc iterate over list elements, i.e. over the columns.

Comment: OK, that's much clearer. Thank you guys so much.